# Jekyll install: Ruby Gems FFI - missing architecture for ARM64 on Mac (the new M1 models) - is there a fix?

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, ffi, apple-m1

```
./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `require': dlopen(./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle - ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle (LoadError)
```

I'm looking for a fix so that it compiles on the ARM64 platform under Mac OS 11 Big Sur; this is for jekyll